# iPhone 6 stolen iCloud accessed

Tags: icloud

My daughter's phone was stolen. We reported it stolen to the police and the carrier. We told the carrier to discontinue the service to the phone. Then we received an email informing us that our iCloud had been accessed. What info can a hacker get from  her iCloud?

Comment: Did you happen to have Find my iPhone turned on? You may be able to either track it down, or remotely reset it to factory settings. Whichever is preferable to you.

Comment: I wonder how they got the password?  Even if they have the phone the password would have to be typed.  In any case, login to appleid.apple.com and change the password now.  Also as @Froggard mentions log into iCloud.com and see if findmyiphone will locate it

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the configuration, an attacker with access to iCloud may get:

- Contacts.
- Calendar.
- Notes
- Safari bookmarks, navigation history, reading list.
- Reminders
- Passbook contents.
- Location of other Apple devices associated with the same account, with Find my iPhone on.
- Photos taken with any Apple device associated to the same iCloud account, or shared with that account (if iCloud Photo Sharing or iCloud Photo Library was on).
- Access to any document stored on iCloud (Pages, Numbers, Keynote, others).
- A full backup of any iOS device stored on iCloud (including all information on any app installed up to the last backup made).

Change your password immediately if you haven't done so yet.

Having your iOS device stolen and having your iCloud credentials compromised are two unrelated events, unless you happen to have your device unlocked, without password or pin, and have your iCloud password written in plain text somewhere inside of it.